# how to fix this wsl ubuntu into version 2 , in canary build windows 11 home?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> wsl --set-version Ubuntu 2
For information on key differences with WSL 2 please visit https://aka.ms/wsl2
Conversion in progress, this may take a few minutes.
The parameter is incorrect.
Error code: Wsl/Service/CreateVm/E_INVALIDARG
```

[image: this is the error]

Comment: Hello and welcome to AskUbuntu. This is a WSL and not a Ubuntu question. You should ask this at stackoverflow